# Unmet Dependencies while installing R on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, r

I followed the instructions on this [Link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-r-on-ubuntu-14-04)
Ran the following commands sequentially

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E084DAB9
gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install r-base
```

I am getting the following message upon execution of the last command

```
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.3.2-1trusty0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 3.3.2-1trusty0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Since you are using 16.10 not 14.04, you will at least need to change `trusty` to `yakkety` in the first command, I think

Comment: @steeldriver that worked. Thanks a lot! That was a silly mistake on my part.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a repository which is no longer listed in "Other Software"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135089/how-do-i-remove-a-repository-which-is-no-longer-listed-in-other-software)