# How do I remove a repository which is no longer listed in "Other Software"?

Tags: repository

During the last few upgrades I have encountered the error:

```
E:The repository 'http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports Release' no longer has a Release file
```

Until now I have been bypassing this by accepting a partial upgrade when offered by the Update Manager. The error has occurred again when I attempted to upgrade from 18.10 to 19.04, so I will defer this upgrade in case there is a way of removing the problem repository from my system and enabling a standard upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

1. Find the respective line that starts by `deb` in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.
2. Then replace `yakkety-backports` by `disco-backports` in it, if you want to continue receiving backports, or delete the line otherwise.